# Customize login page template for Authkit with Pylons?

Tags: pylons, wsgi, authkit

I'm new to both Pylons and AuthKit.  I have basic authentication via AuthKit working in my application, but I don't know how to customize the template for the login page.  The one included with AuthKit is very generic.

I found [Pylons: Mako Templates in AuthKit](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2007/pylons-mako-templates-in-authkit.html), but I thought there might be a more up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pylons Book has chapters on authorization with AuthKit, among other things it talks about [customizing your signin and signout pages](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/simplesite-tutorial-part-3.html#signing-in-and-signing-out).

Answer (score 0):

The pylons book example for customizing the sign-in page does not work. It throws errors that I am yet to understand.